# h323plus samples error in VS2013

Tags: c++, h.323

I am new in h323plus I need to build a simple h323 client in Vc++ using h323plus lib. I have successfully complied ptlib and h323plus now I am trying to compile sample which is with h323plus in **VS2013** .But I am having following error every time I compile the sample

```
   1>h323plus.lib(h323ep.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public:          __thiscall H323_RFC4103Handler::H323_RFC4103Handler(enum H323Channel::Directions,class  H323Connection &,unsigned int)" (??0H323_RFC4103Handler@@QAE@W4Directions@H323Channel@@AAVH323Connection@@I@Z) referenced in function "public: virtual class H323_RFC4103Handler * __thiscall H323EndPoint::CreateRFC4103ProtocolHandler(enum H323Channel::Directions,class H323Connection &,unsigned int)" (?CreateRFC4103ProtocolHandler@H323EndPoint@@UAEPAVH323_RFC4103Handler@@W4Directions@H323Channel@@AAVH323Connection@@I@Z)
```

Please somebody help me I need it badly done .

Comment: This is question about a very specific software üpackage. I don't think it can be considered a duplicate.

Comment: Answer to the question: What you see is a bug in the VS2012 project file. Either add h323t140.cxx to the VS2012 project or compile the VS2010 or VS2008 project.